# Function to identify problematic datatypes

Tags: r

I just spent several hours debugging some R code, only to discover that the error was due to an `Inf` that had sneaked in during my calculations.  I had checked for `NA`, but hadn't thought to check for `Inf`.

I wrote the following function to help prevent this situation in the future:

```
is.bad <- function(x){
  is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.infinite(x)
}

>     is.bad(c(NA, NaN, Inf, -Inf, 0, 1, 1000, 1e6))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Are there any other special data types in R I should be aware of?

Comment: I believe that `is.bad(x)` is equivalent to `!is.finite(x)` ...

Comment: One thing I regularly stumble over is when R silently converts an 1xn or nx1 matrix into a vector (which you can avoid with foo[bar,,drop=FALSE] for the case that bar selects a single row). For cases like these, `is.matrix()` may be helpful, though I personally always simply use `drop=FALSE` - when I don't forget about it, that is.

Comment: @Ben Bolker: That's perfect.  I can't believe I was using `is.infinite` without considering its oposite.  Please submit as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!is.finite(x)` is equivalent to your `is.bad(x)`; it detects `Inf` (and `-Inf`), `NA`, and `NaN` values.

Comment: You forgot the `!` before the `is.finite(x)`, which is kind of necessary... unfortunately, I can't do a single-character edit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing, `is.null()` could possibly at some point also save you a lot of time. Hard to say in general.

Comment: In general, I'd like to identify problematic observations in my matrix of data before I do my analysis.  I was using `is.na()` to do this, and was replacing `NA` values with medians.  However, an `Inf` value got through this process, and messed up my analysis.

Comment: `is.null` won't catch the specific indexes in a vector that are problematic.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it depends very much on your specific definition of "special" data. I often use optional function arguments with defaults of `NULL` and then test whether these are given with `is.null()`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what you're trying to do. I had a similar problem recently when I was creating a linear model for a bunch of data subsets. What worked for me to get coefficients when they were possible, and an NA instead of a program stopping error message was:

```
Coef <- ifelse(is.numeric(try(coef(lm(y~x, data=DF)), silent=T)), coef(lm(y~x+0, DF)), NA)
```

So I would get a vector

```
 [1] 2.3 4.3 5.4 6.2 2.8 NA 3.2
```

Properly spaced, instead of an error message.